# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1 on for each

Tags: java, foreach, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm new to Java and I'm coding a program that uses some JTables.
I have a button to remove the selected rows, which executes this :

```
public static void removerows() {
    int[] row_indexes = TableCA.table.getSelectedRows();
    for(int i=0;i<row_indexes.length;i++) {
        TableCA.model.removeRow(row_indexes[i]);
    }
}
```

but when it executes, I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:554)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(DefaultTableModel.java:463)
    at fr.diagamma.project.PanelCaisse.removerows(PanelCaisse.java:78)
```

I searched a lot, and I didn't found anything for this case of OutOfBounds.
Thanks for help !

Comment: Looks like you have a `Vector`, instead of a 2D structure.

Comment: What does it means ? :c

Comment: Are the selectedRows numbered starting from 1 or from 0?

Comment: @schtever I think it's 1, not sure, but the first column is 1, so I'll assume the first row too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you reverse the order of the loop:

```
public static void removerows() {
    int[] row_indexes = TableCA.table.getSelectedRows();
    for(int i=row_indexes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        TableCA.model.removeRow(row_indexes[i]);
    } 
}
```

This starts with the last element and removes until it reaches the first.

Because, unless your `row_indexes` has only 1 element, otherwise it is wrong in 2 ways:

1. The indexes in `row_indexes` is no longer updated after the `removeRow()`.
2. If the `row_indexes` is in increasing order, it is easily raise OutOfBoundException.

Comment: It returns me the error "The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int.", and I didn't used a lot for loops, so I can't really advise what to do. (and it is also 3:40am) :/

Comment: Basically just reverse your loop from end to 0. Can you show me what line does that error occurs?

Comment: @BachT The line is this one (in removerows()) : TableCA.model.removeRow(row_indexes[i]);